# Error at if else condition parsing

Tags: json, sqlite

I am trying to fetch JSON data from an url and storing in sqlite db.From sqlite db i am converting the data in to JSON array of objects and using that values i am tryinf to perform if and else condition I have n no of objects in JSON created_at and field3 is the data to be performed in this if field3 is 0 i have to ignore and if field3 is 1 we have to calculate the date n time diff from that obj date n time to the next obj where field3 end with 1.My code is as follows.

```
function renderList1(tx,result){ 
    newJson = [ ];
    if (result != null && result.rows != null) {
        for (var k = 0; k < result.rows.length; k++) {
            var row = result.rows.item(k);
            newJson[k] = { created_at:row.Created_at,entry_id:row.entry_id,field1:row.Field1,field2:row.Field2,field3:row.Field3 };
        }
    }
    var jsonAll = JSON.stringify(newJson);
    console.log(jsonAll);
    var feeds = $.parseJSON(jsonAll);
    console.log(feeds);

    power();
    function power(){
    for (var i=0;i<feeds.length;i++) //feeds contain the JSON data
    {
        if(feeds[i]["field3"] === "1"){       
        //Start Time
        var d1 = new Date(feeds[i]["created_at"]);
        console.log(d1);
        for (var j=i+1;j<feeds.length;j++) //compare objects starting from 'i' till next "1" is found
        {   
            if(feeds[j]["field3"] === "0")  
            {
                //End Time
                var d2 = new Date(feeds[j]["created_at"]);
                console.log(d2);
                j=feeds.length;
            }
        }
        //Time difference in milli seconds
        var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
        var diffInHours= diff / 1000diff/ 3600 / 1000;
        console.log(diffInHours);
        var pow = Powercon * diffInHours;
        console.log(pow);
    }else{
        console.log("Field3 is 0");
        }
    }
}
```

JSON Data:

```
[
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T08:53:46Z",
    "entry_id": 37368,
    "field1": "14",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T09:03:54Z",
    "entry_id": 37369,
    "field1": "14",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T09:14:02Z",
    "entry_id": 37370,
    "field1": "14",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T09:24:03Z",
    "entry_id": 37371,
    "field1": "15",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T09:34:06Z",
    "entry_id": 37372,
    "field1": "15",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T09:44:09Z",
    "entry_id": 37373,
    "field1": "15",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T09:54:12Z",
    "entry_id": 37374,
    "field1": "15",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T10:04:20Z",
    "entry_id": 37375,
    "field1": "15",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T10:24:20Z",
    "entry_id": 37376,
    "field1": "15",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T10:44:27Z",
    "entry_id": 37377,
    "field1": "15",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T10:54:30Z",
    "entry_id": 37378,
    "field1": "15",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T11:04:34Z",
    "entry_id": 37379,
    "field1": "16",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T11:14:37Z",
    "entry_id": 37380,
    "field1": "16",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T11:24:40Z",
    "entry_id": 37381,
    "field1": "15",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T11:34:43Z",
    "entry_id": 37382,
    "field1": "15",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T11:44:46Z",
    "entry_id": 37383,
    "field1": "15",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T11:54:49Z",
    "entry_id": 37384,
    "field1": "16",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T12:04:53Z",
    "entry_id": 37385,
    "field1": "15",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T12:14:56Z",
    "entry_id": 37386,
    "field1": "15",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
},
{
    "created_at": "2017-04-12T12:25:00Z",
    "entry_id": 37387,
    "field1": "16",
    "field2": "0",
    "field3": "0"
}
]
```

I tried above code when i run the i got a problem at if and else conditions if field3 is equal to 1 it should perform if condition but it is going to else condition.Can anyone help me where it is going wrong???Thankyou

Comment: Did you try if(feeds[i]["field3"] === 1){ ? Might be its integer.

Comment: @Anusha try `if(feeds[i]["field3"] == "1")`

Comment: Its working now.tq@abhiklpm

Comment: Its working tq@user3441151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(feeds[i]["field3"] === 1){
```

Should solve the problem. Its treated as an integer. Also you should consider using higher order functions or [lodash.js](http://lodash.js) which would be very helpful in array manipulation and make your code more easy to manage and readable.